# What is meant by "Domain Services"?

Tags: wcf, service, dns, ria, domainservices

I am unable to get clear picture of Domain Services when studying about WCF RIA services.

Can anyone explain to me what the role of domain services is?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707373(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: Related question, partial duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920616/domain-service-vs-wcf-service

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707373%28v=vs.91%29.aspx):

> Domain services are Windows
>   Communication Foundation (WCF)
>   services that encapsulate the business
>   logic of a WCF RIA Services
>   application. A domain service exposes
>   a set of related operations in the
>   form of a service layer. When you
>   define a domain service, you specify
>   the data operations that are permitted
>   through the domain service.
>
> When designing a domain service, you
>   should think of the domain service as
>   a set of related tasks that you expect
>   users to perform in your application.
>   Typically, such tasks involve a small
>   group of closely-related entities. For
>   example, in an expense reporting
>   application, you might expose entities
>   for expense reports, line items, and
>   details. You might, then, place
>   entities for accounts and payments in
>   a separate domain service.

[This related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920616/domain-service-vs-wcf-service) may also be of some use.